# Trouble with columns in Bootstrap

Tags: bootstrap-4

Two questions in one:

1. I need to split the whole HTML "body" into two columns, ideally everything before "Some day ..." should be in one column, and the text "some day ..." in the second.
2. The images should be three in one row, I wrap them in one "row", but they are still wrapped.
   I attach the code:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Left Half -->
    <div class="col col-sm col-md">

      <!-- Logo -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="logo">
            <div class="paw_logo">
              <div class="el1"></div>
              <div class="el2"></div>
              <div class="el3"></div>
              <div class="el4"></div>
              <div class="rect1"></div>
              <div class="rect2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="logo_text">PetsPaw</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Hello Square -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Hi Stranger!</h1>
          <p>Welcome to my test project!</p>
          <h3>Lets start using The Dogs API</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Selection zone -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-auto">
          <div class="votingpic">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="votingimg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-auto">
          <div class="dogpic">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="dogimg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-col-sm-auto">
          <div class="gallerypic">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="galleryimg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md col-sm">

        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3">

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Right Half -->
    <div class="col col-sm col-md">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Some day there will be something</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your two columns seem fine. The trouble with your interior image columns is that they're acting like they're on a mobile display because the column around them is narrow. They're full width in that case. Override that with `col-4`. You probably also want the responsive image class on the images.

```css
.row>* {
  background: rgba(255, 0, 0, .1);
}

.row>*:first-child {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 255, .1);
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="undefined" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <!-- Left Half -->
    <div class="col col-sm col-md">

      <!-- Logo -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="logo">
            <div class="paw_logo">
              <div class="el1"></div>
              <div class="el2"></div>
              <div class="el3"></div>
              <div class="el4"></div>
              <div class="rect1"></div>
              <div class="rect2"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="logo_text">PetsPaw</div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto"></div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Hello Square -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Hi Stranger!</h1>
          <p>Welcome to my test project!</p>
          <h3>Lets start using The Dogs API</h3>
        </div>
      </div>

      <!-- Selection zone -->
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="votingpic">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-fluid votingimg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="dogpic">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-fluid dogimg">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
          <div class="gallerypic">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" class="img-fluid galleryimg">
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col col-md col-sm">

        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3">

        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-sm-3">

        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <!-- Right Half -->
    <div class="col col-sm col-md">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
          <h1>Some day there will be something</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```